# how to convert a html5 canvas image to a json object?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

hi i have to covert a set of images to a json object.But, as a first step i was trying to do it for a single image but i don't know whether the json object is created or not.please help me to check whether the object is created.
this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>HTML5 Example: Canvas</title>
<script>
      function drawOnCanvas() {
        var ctx=document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext('2d');
        var image=new Image();
        image.src="2000.png";
        image.onload=function() {
          ctx.drawImage(image,140,0);
        }
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, mycanvas.width, mycanvas.height);
    var jsontext=JSON.stringify(imageData.data);
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', drawOnCanvas, true);
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="1000" height="1000" id="mycanvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+use+javascript+console

Comment: ... Why the heck are you mentioning JSON?

Comment: This is a valid question. How can we get a _string_ out of `canvas ImageData`?

Answer (score 3):

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(5, 5, 300, 250);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();

canvas.addEventListener("click", function (){
  var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    console.log(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  var c2 = document.getElementById("c2");
   var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
    ctx2.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LcnbX/

ctx.getImageData() will return an object
JSON.stringify(data) will generate json string  for you(see the console)

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i didn't get the second image and i don't know why

Comment: you click the first image.  the event listener will get data in first canvas and  render it to the second canvas

Comment: Thanks this is a nice solution, but it generates real big JSON, in my case 13mb for a 640x480px sized canvas with nothing but a red circle. So it may be a option to some people here to just save the parameters of your drawing manually in a JSON and to send and redraw it on the other client.