# How to save canvas data with data-controlid?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**Goal:** To save the data contained within a canvas image (and when you hover a mouse over the image) from a website to an easily manipulated data format like json or csv?

**Tools:** I only have access to the data via my web browser (Google Chrome) as the website I want to save the data from is a paid subscription service.

**My level of skill:** Beginner, I have done some online tutorials on HTML and javascript.

**What I've Tried:** I've gone through Stack Overflow and searched Google and the closest fit is [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058707/how-to-convert-a-html5-canvas-image-to-a-json-object).  The problem however is that the canvas tag looks like this:

```
<canvas width="483" height="280" data-controlid="f443dab8-51fb-470e-8315-6c51cd86d789"></canvas>
```

...and the associated div looks like this:

```
<div data-controlid="f443dab8-51fb-470e-8315-6c51cd86d789_Hover" style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; z-index: 1010; left: 770px; top: 508px; display: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Value: £49061 (percentile: 6%)<br>Year: 13</div>
```

My idea was to use Chrome's Console, enter a few lines of Javascript, and copy and paste any outputs, but I have no idea what "data-controlid" is even after a few Google searches.  From the Chrome Console I've tried a few lines of Javascript using getElementById or getElementsByTagName and have had no luck as it returns undefined.

All help and explanations greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show what you've tried - you refer to that link as "the closest answer", so clearly you've tried to fit the answer to your needs and failed - show what you've tried, not what others have done

Comment: re-reading your question - you may come across a CORS issue, i.e. the site you want to get data from may not want you to do that in the browser

Comment: _“but I have no idea what "data-controlid" is even after a few Google searches”_ – it’s a [custom data attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes); anyone building a website can make up their own to store whatever data they need – so it is to be expected that you won’t find much on google if you search for attribute names “invented” by a particular site for their own purposes.

Comment: Ditto @CBroe's comment. Any "data-" part of an HTML tag is for the use of that particular app and is not usable without the JavaScript code that makes use of that "data-". So your "data-controlid" is a dead end unless you examine the associated JavaScript that really makes the magic. ;-)